# What is the meaning of overwhelming in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of overwhelming in below context?

Source of information: https://youtu.be/TZgxhGk3N20?t=106

Isn't this overwhelming to know that there are billions of people out there who are willing to share their happiness and sadness with you.

I understand that meaning of overwhelming is something in great extent.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of *to be overwhelmed* is to be overcome by a flood or an avalanche, or to be defeated by a much greater force. Metaphorically, it means to be overcome by strong emotion. So, *overwhelming* does indeed often mean *very great*, but in this context it means "Doesn't it make you feel really emotional?"